# Google Pay Web v2 "Payment method not supported" on mobile

Tags: android, braintree, google-pay

I am implementing Google Pay Web API v2 and I am seeing this error on Chrome for Android

```
code: 9
message: "The payment method "https://google.com/pay" is not supported" name: "NotSupportedError"
statusCode: "CANCELED"
```

Using the older API, we have no issues, but we need to update to the newer API.

Tested on Desktop (Chrome), iOS (Chrome and Safari) and Android (Chrome). The only one that is broken is Chrome on Android. Huawei and Samsung devices were tested, both failed.

The button is rendered but tapping gives no feedback. The error above is in the console (use USB debugging to see it)

To note; GPay is being implementing within Braintree, so I'm curious as to whether that could be causing issues?

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. We will need to take a look at your code as well as your account to debug further. Please contact our [support team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) with a code snippet and your merchant ID and we would be happy to take a look.

Comment: I tried to answer my own question, but it didn't work. It turned out that despite having an SSL, it was invalid (out of date i think) and after updating it, everything was working fine. I only managed to figure it out from stepping through our JS code, and I believe an error about the SSL was thrown but ultimately this was the error being piped through to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the google app is not installed as a primary payment app.

Comment: I solved it, please see my comment above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204734/google-pay-web-v2-payment-method-not-supported-on-mobile/63079283#comment101007483_57204734